# How to get timestamp of current month, first day of month, zero hour

Tags: php, date, timestamp, strtotime

I am trying to get the timestamp of the first day of the month at 00:00:00.

For example, the timestamp of Jan 01 2012 00:00:00

I'm doing this:

```
$test_month = time(); // Seconds
$test_month = date('M', $test_month); // This month
$test_month = strtotime($test_month); // Timestamp of this month
echo $test_month;
```

This is returning zero hour of the current day of the month, not the start of the month.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo date( 'F jS Y h:i:s A', strtotime( 'first day of ' . date( 'F Y')));
```

This will output:

```
June 1st 2012 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Wow, I didnt even know 'first day of' existed. Great! Thanks.

Comment: @JohnRobinson - You're welcome! It's actually documented on the [list of supported relative times](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). If my post answered your question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: You don't need to use date('F Y'), you can just use `strtotime('first day of this month')`. You can even add a timestamp of another time as the second argument to get the first day of it's month.

Comment: `strtotime("first day of this month midnight")`. Adding **midnight** will result in 12:00AM.

Comment: Doesn't look like a rememberable solution to me, because of the usings of the F, jS placeholders. Would prefer the database format like in the other answers. Whereas simply using `strtotime('first of this month')` (without date parameter) seems to be a good, possibly rememberable solution, too.

Answer (score 18):

Try this

```
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-01 00:00:00')); // == 1338534000
```

Which translates to:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time); // == 2012-06-01 00:00:00
```

Read the PHP manual on the [date()](http://php.net/date) and [time()](http://php.net/time) functions.

Comment: Looks like a more intuitive solution to me than the one of @nickb https://stackoverflow.com/a/11236766/669210. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
echo date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime("first day of this month"));
```

This outputs:

```
2017-05-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: This answer looks also cleaner than the solution in stackoverflow.com/a/11236766/669210, because the format is more frequently used, I think.